# No valid ‘aps-environment’ entitlement string found for application on app store

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, apple-push-notifications

I am facing issues in receiving push notification of production environment, Device successfully receiving push in development environment.

In production,
Its showing “No valid ‘aps-environment’ entitlement string found for application on app store”

**ionic v1**

**I checked source, there is no file of entitlement but i enabled “Capabilities - Push Notification”.**

Any solution? Please check the screenshot[image]

Answer (score 0):

First turn off the capabilities for Push Notification.
Then turn it on again.

It should add the entitlements file again.

In BuildSettings, check entitlement file name and path.

`Target > Build Settings > Code Signing > Code Signing Entitlements`